# element 0 of tensors does not require grad and ... のデバッグ方法が知りたいです。

Tags: python, python3, tensorflow, pytorch

以下のようなエラーが出たのですがどのようにデバッグを進めればよいでしょうか？

```
Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

いくつか調べていくうちに`required_value=True`であることを確認しろとあったのでそれだけは確認しました。

モデルは以下サイトのT5FineTunerというものを使用しています。
https://github.com/sonoisa/t5-japanese/blob/main/t5_japanese_article_generation.ipynb

```
class T5FineTuner(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, hparams):
        super().__init__()
        self.save_hyperparameters(hparams)

        # 事前学習済みモデルの読み込み
        self.model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(hparams.model_name_or_path)

        # トークナイザーの読み込み
        self.tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained(hparams.tokenizer_name_or_path, is_fast=True)

    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask=None, decoder_input_ids=None,
                decoder_attention_mask=None, labels=None):
        """順伝搬"""
        return self.model(
            input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask,
            decoder_input_ids=decoder_input_ids,
            decoder_attention_mask=decoder_attention_mask,
            labels=labels
        )

    def _step(self, batch):
        """ロス計算"""
        labels = batch["target_ids"]

        # All labels set to -100 are ignored (masked),
        # the loss is only computed for labels in [0, ..., config.vocab_size]
        labels[labels[:, :] == self.tokenizer.pad_token_id] = -100

        outputs = self(
            input_ids=batch["source_ids"],
            attention_mask=batch["source_mask"],
            decoder_attention_mask=batch['target_mask'],
            labels=labels
        )

        loss = outputs[0]
        return loss

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        """訓練ステップ処理"""
        loss = self._step(batch)
        self.log("train_loss", loss)
        return {"loss": loss}

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        """バリデーションステップ処理"""
        loss = self._step(batch)
        self.log("val_loss", loss)
        return {"val_loss": loss}

    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        """テストステップ処理"""
        loss = self._step(batch)
        self.log("test_loss", loss)
        return {"test_loss": loss}

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        """オプティマイザーとスケジューラーを作成する"""
        model = self.model
        no_decay = ["bias", "LayerNorm.weight"]
        optimizer_grouped_parameters = [
            {
                "params": [p for n, p in model.named_parameters()
                            if not any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)],
                "weight_decay": self.hparams.weight_decay,
            },
            {
                "params": [p for n, p in model.named_parameters()
                            if any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)],
                "weight_decay": 0.0,
            },
        ]
        optimizer = AdamW(optimizer_grouped_parameters,
                          lr=self.hparams.learning_rate,
                          eps=self.hparams.adam_epsilon)
        self.optimizer = optimizer

        scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(
            optimizer, num_warmup_steps=self.hparams.warmup_steps,
            num_training_steps=self.t_total
        )
        self.scheduler = scheduler

        return [optimizer], [{"scheduler": scheduler, "interval": "step", "frequency": 1}]

    def get_dataset(self, tokenizer, type_path, args):
        """データセットを作成する"""
        return TsvDataset(
            tokenizer=tokenizer,
            data_dir=args.data_dir,
            type_path=type_path,
            input_max_len=args.max_input_length,
            target_max_len=args.max_target_length)

    def setup(self, stage=None):
        """初期設定（データセットの読み込み）"""
        if stage == 'fit' or stage is None:
            train_dataset = self.get_dataset(tokenizer=self.tokenizer,
                                             type_path="train.tsv", args=self.hparams)
            self.train_dataset = train_dataset

            val_dataset = self.get_dataset(tokenizer=self.tokenizer,
                                           type_path="dev.tsv", args=self.hparams)
            self.val_dataset = val_dataset

            self.t_total = (
                (len(train_dataset) // (self.hparams.train_batch_size * max(1, self.hparams.n_gpu)))
                // self.hparams.gradient_accumulation_steps
                * float(self.hparams.num_train_epochs)
            )

    def train_dataloader(self):
        """訓練データローダーを作成する"""
        return DataLoader(self.train_dataset,
                          batch_size=self.hparams.train_batch_size,
                          drop_last=True, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)

    def val_dataloader(self):
        """バリデーションデータローダーを作成する"""
        return DataLoader(self.val_dataset,
                          batch_size=self.hparams.eval_batch_size,
                          num_workers=4)
```

Comment: 「いくつか調べていくうちにrequired_value=Trueであることを確認しろとあったのでそれだけは確認しました。」それで結果はTrueだったということですか？

Comment: そうです。全てのレイヤー？がTrueでした。

Comment: 実行したコードとエラーメッセージ全文を掲載されると回答がつきやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: 実行環境についても追記しましょう。（OSの種類、Pythonやモジュールのバージョン、GPUについてなど）

Comment: エラーメッセージに「require grad」とあるのでGPU関連の問題ではないでしょうか？確認されてはどうでしょうか？